# What is the correct way to use specific rule for specific pattern match when parsing an expression?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, parsing

**update:**
Thanks for the answers below. But I noticed they do not handle the following special cases: `lis=1` and `lis=z` , `lis=1/z` and `lis=-z` as these are also considered legal input as given in the question below.  It is easy to add special case processing for these, by making them `lis={1}` and `lis={z}` etc... before calling the parser (this is what I actually had to do myself). but it will be nice if this was incorporated as special pattern/rule as well. I could not do it myself inside `Alternative` and had to check for this before as special case.

To make sure what is the input, I'll clarify it again:  Each term is of the form `c*z^n` where there can be *one or more terms*. i.e. `lis= term1+term2+term3...`

In each term, `c` can be any numerical value, and `n` can be any numerical value (positive or negative). The result will be list of `{{c,n},.....}`, one entry for each term. Even if there is one term only, it should work.

Examples to verify against:

```
lis=1   --->  {{1,0}}
lis=z ----> {{1,1}}
lis=-z --->{{-1,1}}
lis=1/z  ---->{{1,-1}}
lis=1+z^-1 --->{{1,0},{1,-1}}
lis=1/z^3 + 3/z + 3 z + z^3 -->{{1,-3},{3,-1},{3,1},{1,3}}
lis=6 + 1/z^4 + 4/z^2 + 4 z^2 + z^4 -->{{6, 0}, {1, -4}, {4, -2}, {4, 2}, {1, 4}}
```

**Original question**

The hammer I use now for everything I see that needs parsing with patterns is `Cases`.

So, I was trying to write a simple pattern based parser that accepts any output from `Expand(f[z])`  where `f[z]` is rational function of `z` only. For example, it take such input as

```
Expand[(z + 1/z)^4]
(*6 + 1/z^4 + 4/z^2 + 4 z^2 + z^4*)
```

or

```
Expand[(z + 1/z)^3]
(*1/z^3 + 3/z + 3 z + z^3*)
```

or `1` or `z` or `z^-1` or `1+z` and so on. So the input can be thought of as power series in `z`. All terms are in this form. So it is well defined what it is.

The output of the parser will be a list that shows the coefficient of each term, and the exponent of `z`.   So given the input `6+(1/z^4) + 4/z^2 + 4 z^2 + z^4` the output will be

```
 {{6,0},{1,-4},{4,-2},{4,2},{1,4}}
```

The best I can come up with is this:

```
lis = 6 + 1/z^4 + 4/z^2 + 4 z^2 + z^4
Cases[lis, Alternatives[x_. Power[z, e_.], 
                       Times[x_, Power[z, e_.]], 
                       x_.] :> {x, e}]
```

The problem is that the above generates

```
  {{6},{1,-4},{4,-2},{4,2},{1,4}}
```

and not

```
  {{6,0},{1,-4},{4,-2},{4,2},{1,4}}
```

This is because the pattern that matched x_. (the last one in the `Alternatives` does not have an `e` in it, and Mathematica replaced the `e` with the Null sequence as documented in help. Another problem with the above, is that `x_.` has to the last one in the alternatives. If I had wrote this instead:

```
Cases[lis, Alternatives[x_., x_. Power[z, e_.], Times[x_, Power[z, e_.]]] :> 
       {x, e}]
```

Then it would not have worked (another thing to worry about).

Ok, this is all fine, except now the output is not symmetric and needs special case processing.

What I was hoping to do is something like this

```
 Cases[lis, Alternatives[x_. Power[z, e_.] :> {x,e} , 
                         Times[x_, Power[z, e_.]] :> {x,e}, 
                         x_. :> {x,0}] 
       ]
```

ie. have a specific rule for each specific pattern. The above is much easier to work with, since now I can specific the output for each pattern instead of having all pattern target one output. But the above of course is not valid Mathematica code and `Cases` does not like it.

Are there such general ways of doing the pattern matching that allows one to write specific rules for specific pattern?  It does not have to use `Cases` as long as it follows this general approach.

I know that one can probably use the Polynomial specific functions (such as `CoefficientRules`, `CoefficientList`, and related functions to do this for this case, but I am more interested in this general approach so I can learn how to use it for things other that this example)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just define a new function that could take different inputs, either through overloading or using `If`, `Which`, or `Switch`.

```
Clear[f]
f[x_. Power[z, e_.]] := {x, e}
f[Times[x_, Power[z, e_.]]] := {x, e}
f[x_] := {x, 0}

Cases[lis, y : Alternatives[x_., x_. Power[z, e_.], Times[x_, Power[z, e_.]]] :> f[y]]
(* {{6, 0}, {1, -4}, {4, -2}, {4, 2}, {1, 4}} *)
```

---

**Update**: Below is the most general way I could think of to achieve what the OP wants while still using `Cases`.

`HoldPattern` is needed to prevent `z^0` from evaluating before it is matched. `FreeQ` is needed to make sure that the matched coefficient is free from `z`**:

```
Clear[coeff, z]

(* Applies to plus expressions *)
coeff[expr_Plus] := 
 Cases[expr, HoldPattern[(c : _?(FreeQ[#, z] &) : 1) (zVar : z^e_. : z^0)] :> {c, e}]

(* Applies to standalone expressions: nest them in a list first before using Cases *)
coeff[expr_] := 
 Cases[{expr}, HoldPattern[(c : _?(FreeQ[#, z] &) : 1) (zVar : z^e_. : z^0)] :> {c, e}]

{#, coeff@#} & /@ {1, z, -z, 1/z, 1 + z^-1, 1/z^3 + 3/z + 3 z + z^3, 6 + 1/z^4 + 4/z^2 + 4 z^2 + z^4} // 
 Grid[Prepend[#, {"expr", "coeff[expr]"}], Frame -> All] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> **

Otherwise things like this might happen:

```
Cases[{z^2}, HoldPattern[(c : _ : 1) (zVar : z^e_. : z^0)] :> {c, e}]
(* {{z^2, 0}} *)
```

That's because `z^2` matches the first term, while `z^0` matches the second term. This is not what we want, which is `1` for the first term, and `z^2` for the second term.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is to use `Replace` with `Sow`/`Reap`:

```
Scan[
   Replace[#, {
      x_. Power[z, e_.] :> Sow[{x, e}],
      Times[x_, Power[z, e_.]] :> Sow[{x, e}],
      x_ :> Sow[{x, 0}]}] &,
   lis] // Reap // #[[-1, -1]] &
```

> {{6, 0}, {1, -4}, {4, -2}, {4, 2}, {1, 4}}

However, the wildcard `x_` could be tricky if you needed to operate deeper in the expression.

It seems like there should be a way to use `Cases` and insert `Sow` inside `Condition` (`/;`) but I have not managed to get that approach working. Maybe someone else can figure it out :)

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to use `ReplaceAll` on the rhs of `RuleDelayed` in the second argument of `Cases`:

```
rules = Alternatives[x_. Power[z, e_.] :> {x, e}, Times[x_, Power[z, e_.]] :> {x, e},
                     x_. :> {x, 0}]; (* your prefered second argument for Cases *)

Cases[lis, pat : rules[[All, 1]] :> (pat /. List @@ rules)]
(*  {{6, 0}, {1, -4}, {4, -2}, {4, 2}, {1, 4}} *)
```

**Update:**

```
exp = {1, z, -z, 1/z, 1 + z^-1, 1/z^3 + 3/z + 3 z + z^3, 6 + 1/z^4 + 4/z^2 + 4 z^2 + z^4};
cF = Cases[If[Head[#] === Plus, #, {#}], 
           pat : rules[[All, 1]] :> (pat /. List @@ rules)] &    (* thanks: @algohi *)

Grid[{{"expr", "cF[expr]"}, ## & @@ ({#, cF@#} & /@ exp)}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: You can edit you answer to be like this :    Cases[If[Head[lis] === Plus, lis, {lis}], 
 pat : rules[[All, 1]] :> (pat /. List @@ rules)] to take all cases of the OP.

Comment: @Algohi, thank you so much. That was one of the things I tried after Nasser's update, but somehow I could not get it to work. Now -- with a fresh session -- it works :)

Answer (score 5):

**The General Case**

Alas, `Cases` does not permit multiple replacement rules.  But `Replace` does, although we must take care to 1) create an output list, 2) omit non-matching elements and 3) operate only upon the first level:

```
lis = 6 + 1/z^4 + 4/z^2 + 4 z^2 + z^4;

Replace[List @@ lis, {x_. z^e_. :> {x, e}, x_ :> {x, 0}, _ :> Sequence[]}, {1}]

(* {{6,0},{1,-4},{4,-2},{4,2},{1,4}} *)
```

**This Specific Case**

`Cases` can do the job at hand if we explicitly note the possibility that `e` might be bound to an empty sequence:

```
Cases[lis, x_. z^e_. | x_ :> ({x, e} /. {s_} :> {s, 0})]

(* {{6,0},{1,-4},{4,-2},{4,2},{1,4}} *)
```

**What Could Have Been...**

By rights, we should have been able to bind a value to `e` in alternatives from which it is missing by writing:

```
Cases[lis, x_. z^e_. | PatternSequence[x_, e_:0] :> {x, e}]
```

... but unfortunately this expression does not do what we want due to a long-standing bug in *Mathematica*:

```
MatchQ[{1, 2}, {a_, b_}]                     (* True *)
MatchQ[{1, 2}, {a_, b_:0}]                   (* True *)
MatchQ[{1, 2}, {PatternSequence[a_, b_]}]    (* True *)
MatchQ[{1, 2}, {PatternSequence[a_, b_:0]}]  (* False -- BUG! *)
```

Comment: Is there a Q&A about the bug mentioned here?  If not would you please start one?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I added [Unexpected pattern matching behaviour: PatternSequence vs. Optional](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72290/142).