# Unexpected pattern matching behaviour: PatternSequence vs. Optional

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching, optional-arguments

**Bug fixed in 10.1**

---

Consider the following pattern-matching expressions:

```
MatchQ[{1, 2}, {a_, b_}]                     (* True *)
MatchQ[{1, 2}, {a_, b_:0}]                   (* True *)
MatchQ[{1, 2}, {PatternSequence[a_, b_]}]    (* True *)
MatchQ[{1, 2}, {PatternSequence[a_, b_:0]}]  (* False *)
```

The last result surprises me.  I would have expected it to return `True` just like the others.  I suspect a bug, but does this behaviour conform to some pattern-matching principle that I have overlooked?

Comment: I reported this issue to WRI some years ago, but never received a diagnosis.

Comment: Interesting. Yes, probably a bug. I'll try to have a look when I get a chance.

Comment: To my interest `MatchQ[{1, 2}, {PatternSequence[a_, b_.]}]` throws messages but returns `True`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Working on it (and the issue from the original post).

Comment: @Daniel http://i.stack.imgur.com/k7L5x.gif

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed in 10.1 (windows)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code

```
MatchQ[{1, 2}, {a_, b_}]                     
MatchQ[{1, 2}, {a_, b_: 0}]                 
MatchQ[{1, 2}, {PatternSequence[a_, b_]}]    
MatchQ[{1, 2}, {PatternSequence[a_, b_: 0]}]
```