# Pattern matching with List and Optional

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching, sequence, optional-arguments

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier and persists through 11.1.1**

> Thank you for bringing this to our attention. I have filed a report with our developers.

---

Why does this

```
{42.`}~MatchQ~(x0 : _List)
{42.`}~MatchQ~(x0 : {___})

{42.`}~MatchQ~(x0 : _List : {1.})
{42.`}~MatchQ~(x0 : {___} : {1.})
```

give

> True
>
> True
>
> True
>
> False

Instead of all true?

Comment: In addition `{42.}~MatchQ~(x0 : {__} : {1.})` yields `False` but `{42.}~MatchQ~(x0 : {_} : {1.})` yields `True`. And `Trace`ing doesn't illuminate anything: `Trace[{42.}~MatchQ~(x0 : {___} : {1.})]` yields `{MatchQ[{42.}, x0 : {___} : {1.}], False}`.

Comment: So I guess this is a bug?

Comment: I filed a report.

Comment: similar: [(72290)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72290/142).

Comment: @WReach We have to get Daniel here ;)

Comment: "Thank you for bringing this to our attention. I have filed a report with our developers."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug is fixed in our next release.  Note, however, that, that the use of Optional generates a warning now, as the optional value could never possible be used in such pattern:

```
In[14]:= {42.`}~MatchQ~(x0 : {___} : {1.})
During evaluation of In[14]:= Optional::optloose: Optional pattern 
x0:{___}:{1.} has no enclosing pattern so no optional value can be matched.
Out[14]= True
```

Comment: Thanks. I was also notified that this is fixed in 11.2.

Comment: Now `x /. b_: 0 + x :> -b` fails in 11.2 but works in 11.0.1.  To get it to work in 11.2 had to add parentheses: `x /. (b_: 0) + x :> -b`