# Optional in MatchQ

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-test, optional-arguments

Why isn't the first one `True` in:

```
MatchQ[{1}, Optional[{__Integer}, {2}]]
MatchQ[{1}, Optional[{_Integer}, {2}]]
MatchQ[{1}, {__Integer}]
```

> False
>
> True
>
> True

or in:

```
MatchQ[{1}, p : {__Integer} : {2}]
MatchQ[{1}, p : {_Integer} : {2}]
MatchQ[{1}, p : {__Integer}]
```

> False
>
> True
>
> True

> `p:v` is a pattern object that represents an expression of the form `p`, which, if omitted, should be replaced by `v`.

So my guess was that

```
MatchQ[{1}, Optional[{__Integer}, {2}]]
```

should be equivalent to:

```
MatchQ[{1}, {__Integer}]
```

And even if you can explain that, why are middle examples `True`?

Comment: The first one returns `False`. I am using version 11.1.1. But the others are `True`

Comment: @happyfish I meant it should be `True`, sorry for confusion :)

Comment: Duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124801/121?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard correct, missed that one.