# PatternSequence, Optional and _Symbol

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier, partially fixed in 10.1 and persisting through 11.3**

---

> [CASE: 4075992] *confirmed*

*Note:* See [(72290)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72290/36508) for the fixed part of the bug.

Consider the following example:

```
bar[PatternSequence[a_Symbol, b_String: ""]] := {{a}, {b}}

bar[a]
bar[a, "b"]
(* bar[a] *) (* EXPECTED: {{a}, {""}}*)
(* {{a}, {"b"}} *)
```

Note how the first example does not evaluate, meaning the `Optional` value for `b` doesn't match for some reason. What's stranger is that the following does work (The only difference being the use of `_String` instead of `_Symbol`):

```
bar2[PatternSequence[a_String, b_String: ""]] := {{a}, {b}}

bar2["a"]
bar2["a", "b"]
(* {{"a"}, {""}} *)
(* {{"a"}, {"b"}} *)
```

While I'm pretty sure this is a bug (I've submitted a bug report already, but please do correct me if I'm wrong), I am in need of a workaround, which is one of the reasons I'm also posting it here.

For reference, what I'm really trying to do (because the above example does not make any sense) is something like the following:

```
pat = _Integer | PatternSequence[_Symbol | _String, _String : ""]

bar[p : pat] := {p}

bar[1]
bar[a]
bar["a"]
bar["a", "b"]
bar[a, "b"]
(* {1} *)
(* bar[a] *) (* EXPECTED: {a} *)
(* {"a"} *)
(* {"a", "b"} *)
(* {a, "b"} *)
```

(With `pat` used in several definitions)

Comment: this is probably not you want but, `pat =_Integer | PatternSequence[_Symbol | _String, s___String : ""]/; Length[{s}]<=1` gives the expected result.

Comment: @kglr No, that should work perfectly fine in my case, thanks a lot! But it looks like the `Optional` part in your pattern does not apply in the problematic cases, so it can be left away (luckily, this doesn't matter for me, as I'm handling the default values later on)

Comment: In v10.0.2 `bar[a, "b"]` won't evaluate either.

Comment: @Szabolcs That's also what I have found - as far as I can tell, this is the bug described in the linked question which has been fixed in 10.1. So the question is now whether this bug here should be considered to have been introduced in 10.1 or whether it has just existed alongside the linked one before.

Comment: The bug described here is present in 9.0 on Windows, I just tested

Comment: @user6014 Thanks for the info, I've updated the information in the question accordingly

Comment: I don't agree with the expected output.  In your second group of examples, `bar[a]` should return `{a,""}` and `bar["a"]` should return `{"a",""}`, since the default value of `""` should always be included if the optional argument is not supplied.

Comment: @QuantumDot I'm pretty sure that's intended: `Cases[{{}}, o : {i_: 2} :> {o, i}]` returns `{{}, 2}`, not `{{2}, 2}`. So it appears as though the `Optional` default is only inserted for the value of the pattern itself, but not the enclosing ones. I'll keep looking for a reference though